Delay in discharging of the capacitor for sequencing purpose
Our aim is to sequence 2 different power supplies i.e. 5 V and -48 V.
On sequence is first "5 V is generated" and then "-48 V is generated" with 120 ms delay.
Off sequence is first "-48 V goes to 0 V" and then "5 V goes to 0 V" with 120 ms delay.
We are using LM3880 sequencer IC with 120 ms delay between its flag outputs to enable 2 different regulators for 5 V and -48 V.
The input supply for both the regulators is 5 V indicated by VCC5V0 in the schematic
The schematic for the same is shown below:
page-1

page-2

page-3

The 5 V output and -48 V output are checked using an oscilloscope.
The Test results are as follows:

Channel 1 (yellow) indicates 5 V output
Channel 2 (green) indicates -48 V output


The below image indicates the outputs when VCC5V0 is turned ON and EN_BUF signal is given high and low.
EN-BUF -> high, then 5 V and -48 V are generated
EN-BUF -> low, then we get 0 V


ON delay between 5 V output and -48 V output


OFF-sequence:
We can observe that there is a ramp when -48 V is going to 0 V.


In this picture, we can observe that -48 V is going low, but is reaching 0 V with more than 25 sec duration to discharge and get to 0V.



The issue we are facing is the LTC3863 is taking more time to discharge as the load current is very low (8 mA). So we tried to implement a discharge circuitry by placing parallel resistors across -48 V but we think it is not ideal as the resistors are getting heated up.
Next, we tried to implement the same thing using a N-channel MOSFET. The circuit for this is given below.

We observed that in this case VGS was always 5 V in the MOSFET even though we turned off the input signal coming to ADP3623 IC. Note that we placed a Zener diode of 12 V rating across the gate and source terminals with cathode terminal at the gate. Please say if there are any issues in this approach.
We want -48 V to go to 0 V before 5V go to 0V with their OFF sequence delay to be 120 ms when the EN-BUF signal goes low.

"We want the 5 V to fall to 0 V and -48 V to go to 0 V within nano seconds" That won't happen. What do you actually need?

@winny I want at off sequence, that -48V to get discharged completely before 5V goes to 0V.

Just wait until 5 V rail reaches 0 V before discharging -48 V rail? Moreover, it will never reach 0 V, just asymptotically get closer and closer. You need more realistic values.

5V and -48V will be on and off only through sequencer(LM3880), when the sequencer enable is high then sequencer Flags will be high(as the sequencer having open drain, we used pull up resistors) and those are connected to the enable pins of the regulator, our issue is -48V is discharging very slowly , as the load for -48V is just 8mA.
due to this 5V is going to 0V first and then -48V is going to 0V, but our off sequence is reverse(i.e. -48V should go to 0V first then after 5V go to 0V).

Discharge the rail which needs to be off first actively? Increase hold-up capacitance until that happens naturally? What happens if the sequence is not what you indented, does anything break?

To switch off the N-channel MOSFET, you require \$V_{GS} \approx 0\$, which can never happen in this arrangement. Moreover, it's wired as a source-follower, and it will always maintain \$V_S\$ a couple of volts below \$V_G\$, which explains why you never see the full −48V at the source.
Here's a solution, probably not the simplest:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When FLAG2 is high, Q1 is off, and so is Q2. They place no load on the −48V supply.
When FLAG2 goes low, indicating that the −48V supply should be discharged, Q1 is switched on, sourcing base current for Q2, which also switches on.
R4 is recommended to limit discharge current to some maximum (100mA here), but you should choose a value suitable to discharge whatever capacitance your −48V supply has quickly enough.
